# Running `play test` on OSX causes a java app to appear in the dock

Tags: java, scala, playframework-2.0, sbt, ebean

This wouldn't be a major issue, but the app is stealing focus every time it goes off.

The app icon that appears in the dock is named `sbt.ForkMain`.

I've traced it down to `ebean.default="models.*"` in the application.conf file.  When this line is commented out, the app dosen't run.  I'm quite sure this has something to do with the ebean server starting up, but it dosen't happen on any of my other machines.

I'm using a brand new installation of OSX 10.8.3, and this happens even in a clean `play new xxxx` folder.

`play! 2.1.0 (using Java 1.6.0_51 and Scala 2.10.0), http://www.playframework.org`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found a way to achieve this in sbt config file:

```
javaOptions in (Test, run) += "-Djava.awt.headless=true"
```

Answer (score 4):

I do not know on how do you add VM arguments in the sbt settings. But given for a normal application, if you wish to not wish show the app on the dock, use:

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

VM argument. Adding this should suffice.

Beware: If you have any JNI code and it uses OS events, then it sometimes result in some abnormal behavior with application not getting the events. Else it works fine.

Comment: I'm not sure where to set it either.  I've tried all the obvious places and it still pops up.

Comment: @Geoist Hmm I am sorry I do not know `sbt` well. But the argument for sure solves the problem for normal application

Comment: `export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Djava.awt.headless=true"` worked.  I still have no idea why this install is any different from the other 2 that are working perfectly.